# I am not able to open Google Account on New Galaxy Ace 3 Phone

Tags: samsung, hardware, google

I have tried to open a Google account but after many attempts have failed. When I tap the Gmail icon I get a window, prompting me to add an account, for either an "Existing" or "New" account. When I tap on either option the WiFi scanner starts up instead. I should get a window with a qwerty keyboard to enable me to register my details for an account; but I do not.

This phone is brand new so I am wondering is the phone faulty or am I doing something wrong. This is my first smart phone which I bought on Ebay but I have not yet registered the Sim card with my provider as I am still using my old phone. Would this make a difference? Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need an internet connection to create or log into your account. As you don't have a mobile internet connection yet, the phone needs to connect to a Wi-Fi network first. That's why it's showing you the Wi-Fi settings right away.